# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Been having trouble getting testing things to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

TL; DR:
I don't know how to get RSpec::Matchers to work in my test/unit/..._test.rb tests has any one succeeded? should I migrate all those tests to the spec folder?

---

So, I'm using cucumber, Test::Unit, and before I started the project there were a bunch of spec tests.

When I was reading up on what testing framework to use for my unit tests, I found RSpec, and thought it was pretty cool... but as it turns out, I didn't actually use any Rspec until I found out about the should be_nil / be_whatever methods. I thought those were pretty cool.

I stuck with sticking tests in the test/(unit|functionals) folders, because it made the most sense (I thought having unit and functional tests in a "spec" folder was really weird and unconventional. I also began using shoulda, which enabled me to do `should "test name"` rather than `it "should..."` which I thought was more concise, and all around more intuitive.

But I recently started using cucumber for view testing, and... that resulted in tons of conflicting gem issues. It was a terrible hassle to get cucumber working with Factory girl, capybara, and the like.

I eventually had to migrate to bundler, because I could never get my environment working.

Anyway, after about a week of messing with the testing environment, cucumber works, functional tests work, and I feel like unit test WOULD work if I hadn't intially used .should be_valid / be_whateven methods.

Has anyone else gotten RSpec::Matchers to work in this scenario?

relevant part of GemFile:

```
group :test do
    gem "cucumber", "~>0.10.3"
    gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
    gem "launchy"
    gem "hpricot"
    gem "gherkin", "~>2.4.0"

    gem "capybara", "0.4.1.2"
    gem "rspec", "~> 1.3.2"
    gem "rack"
    gem "rspec-rails", "~> 1.3.3"

    gem "webrat", "0.7.0"
    gem "database_cleaner"

    gem "factory_girl", "2.1"
    gem "shoulda", :require => nil
    gem "shoulda-matchers", :git => "https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers"
    gem "awesome_print"
    gem "cobravsmongoose"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to : 
[the rspec expectations page talking about integration with Test::Unit](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/test-frameworks/test-unit-integration)

My experience with testing with cucumber, rspec and test::unit leads me to believe that it is all about comfort as long as you are getting the coverage.  I like rspec much more than test.  If you are not really comfortable with test unit, definitely try rspec.  I also know people (and am starting to lean this way myself) that just use cucumber and skip rspec all together (but this can get into a bit of a "religious" discussion).